# JDT - AstParser - How to get object declaration for the caller object

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

This is the code.

```
CompilationUnit cu = prepareCompilationUnitForFile(new File("C:\\Test\\src\\Test.java"));
cu.accept(new ASTVisitor()
{
    public boolean visit(MethodInvocation v)
    {
        System.out.println("> " + v);
        return true;
    }
}
```

How to:

1) verify the calling object is variable? Like `obj.method()`, in this case `obj` is calling object

2) get the declaration of obj. Like `SomeObject obj = new SomeObject()`

Comment: I think you have a typo in your code; shouldn't there be a space between `MethodInvocation` and `v`?

Comment: Yeah, but not in the code, I have made this mistake when pasting the code into the form ;)